# error when passing array variable in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

In my site I have this link called images and what I want is when the user clicks it, it will display the image gallery using fancybox. I use the name attribute to put all the image filename and then using javascript to parse it.

My problem is when using multiple images the fancybox is not loading. but then if I hardcode the filename it is working. I'm not sure why.

Here's my code.

```
$(".imageGallery").click(function() {
        var pURL = $(this).attr("name");
        var pID  = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
        var imageList="";
        var arrUrl = new Array();
        var i=0;            

        if (pURL.indexOf(',') != -1)
        {
            arrUrl = pURL.split(',');
            imageList = arrUrl;
        }else {imageList = pURL;}
        alert(imageList);
        $.fancybox([imageList], {
            'autoScale'             : true,
            'autoDimensions'        : true,
            'speedIn'               : 800,
            'speedOut'              : 800,
            'changeSpeed'           : 500,
            'padding'               : 0,
            'centerOnScroll'        : false,
            'type'                  : 'image',
            'transitionIn'          : 'fade',
            'transitionOut'         : 'fade',  
            'showCloseButton'       : true,
            'titlePosition'         : 'outside',
            'hideOnContentClick'    : true,
            'overlayColor'             : '#1b2642',
            'showNavArrows'         : true
        });
    });
```

Comment: I can't work out from your code sample where you have been modifying it to test a hardcoded filename. Could you elaborate?

Comment: instead of passing imageList in fancybox I use this  /media/5970/monsoon.jpg,/media/14444/monsoon1.jpg,/media/14449/monsoon2.jpg as my image array and it is working. But if I assigned this string to the variable imageList and pass imageList instead, that's when i'm getting the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageList is an array. You need to do this (although why have all the urls in the NAME attribute of something?):

```
if (pURL.indexOf(',') != -1) {
   imageList = pURL.split(',');
}
else {
  imageList = [pURL];
}
alert(imageList);
$.fancybox(imageList, { // no brackets
```

Assuming you are trying the "manual2" version on the demo page

```
$("#manual2").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
        'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
        'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
        {
            'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
            'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
        }
    ], {
        'padding'           : 0,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'image',
        'changeFade'        : 0
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE: to use the second format you could use rel and title:

```
$(".imageGallery").click(function() {
  var pURL = $(this).attr("rel");
  var pTitle = $(this).attr("title");
  var arrUrl = (pURL.indexOf(',') != -1)?pURL.split(','):[pURL];
  var arrTitle = (pTitle.indexOf(',') != -1)?pTitle.split(','):[pTitle];
  var imageList = [];
  for (var i=0;i<arrUrl.length;i++) {
    imageList[i] = { "href":arrUrl[i], "title": arrTitle[i] }
  }
  $.fancybox(imageList, {
```

Comment: Oh I was using rel first but then I use name because I was thinking it might be causing the problem. :D

Comment: @Sherry Anyway, [string] will create an array of one, regardless of commas so your [imagelist] did not work - please try my version

Comment: Thank you. I though the square bracket is required in the fancybox. :D Really appreaciate it.

Comment: I try to add the title in the list but it is not working. I'm trying to pass this string. {'href':'/media/5970/monsoon.jpg','title':'monsoon'}|{'href':'/media/14444/monsoon1.jpg','title':'Monsoon1'}| {'href':'/media/14449/monsoon2.jpg','title':'Monsoon2'}  then split it using "|" but it is not working. Do I need to include the "{" ?